# how to calculate overall RMSE accumulated during several processing steps

Tags: error, rms

1. I have a digital terrain model (DTM) downloaded from NASA's SRTM dataset at a resolution of 1 arc second covering Spain and France. This has a stated RMSE of 9.73m [output 1]
2. I projected this to UTM30N and resampled (bilinear) to 25m x25m cells which seems to be the best cell size approximation for 1 arc second in this geographical area. [output 2]
3. For computational convenience, I then performed a second bilinear resampling on this DTM to 100m x 100m resolution. [output 3]
4. I compared values between output 2 and output 3 at 1000 sampled locations, obtaining an RMSE value of 7.74m

But how can I calculate the overall RMSE accumulated during the processing steps? Here's what I tried:

```
#simple sum of two RMSE scores
sum(9.73,7.74)
[1] 17.47

#product of RMSE scores
9.73*7.74
75.3102

#simple mean of two RMSE scores
sum(9.73,7.74)/2
[1] 8.735

#geometric mean of two RMSE scores
(9.73*7.74)^(1/2)
[1] 8.678145
```

I can see pros and cons to all of these possibilities, but I am not sure which, if any, are right. The product seems wrong, since errors could cancel out, and the two means suggest errors that seem too small given the bilinear aggregation process on top of an already imperfect terrain model. The sum results seem intuitively right, but can RMSE be summed in this way? Any ideas? Thanks